# Customizing Industry standard data models

Tags: erwin

I am considering using a industry standard data model, more specifically ACORD reference data model for an insurance company. The standard model is developed to support data requirements of a a typical property and casualty insurance company.

One question I have is, how do you customize the data models or enhance/change them. For example, the data model has a subject area/domain called Agreement. I would like to use this object to build my Policy table. Do I make a copy of the Agreement object and rename it as Policy and drop the items that I don't need or is there a better/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To enhance an existing model with entities from industry standard model: The best approach would be copying the entity from ACORD model and append it to existing model.
If you are building a brand new Insurance IT database then take the ACORD data model as the base-line and create a new subject area with all your Work-In-Progress entities and customize per your application business needs.
Hope this advice helps.

Answer (score 0):

I gather your question is centered on the policy entity and you are not really asking the more general question of how does one use an external reference model in the development of the internal model for the business.

A policy is a type of agreement that is specific to the insurance industry and probably should appear as a sub-type of agreement.

Remember your enterprise will have other types of agreements that they will deal with, such as:

- Purchasing agreements
- Employment agreements, etc

Sub-typing will facilitate addressing this.

There is something else you might want to consider; policy might need to be further sub-typed:

- There are policies that your customer purchase (e.g. P&C)
- There are policies that the organization purchase (e.g. health
  coverage, workman's compensation, etc.)